# Jenkins Master & Slave

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up Jenkins master and slave over unix.

I have installed tomcat and jenkins.war, Maven , Ant on Master Jenkins Server

Do i need to install Tomcat, Ant and Maven on Slave machines as well?

Answer (score 1):

You only need the Tomcat webserver on the main Jenkins server, not any of the build machines.

If you want to build Maven or Ant projects on those build machine, then yes, you need to ensure that those tools are installed.

However, using the Maven and Ant plugins, these tools can be downloaded and installed automatically on-demand.  Go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System, and configure the versions you want.  Then, when you configure a job, you will be able to select one of those versions to be used.